# Updated to MAMP 3 and lost my database files

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

I recently updated to MAMP 3 and as a result see to have lost all of my database files. When I start the servers, and load up my developed websites it begins a wordpress install from fresh. I can see the db files in the directory but they don't seem to load in phpmyadmin. Does anyone know if it is possible to recover the database file and website to previous functionality or what I can do to restore the site back to normal.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you host is not making backup, there's no way to get the DELETED data back.

however login to cpanel and click on backup, click on generate & download a backup, check if it has a option "system generated backup" and has a button called weekly.

if there's a weekly button, that should give you the backup when the main server owner Ran the backups.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f49/my-database-removed-accidentally-how-recover-155173.html